# Spring Boot REST and entityManagerFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a question regarding spring and some annotations.

First of all, all necessary Classes:

application.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@Transactional
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "de.paddaels")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "de.paddaels")
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

ResourcesRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface ResourcesRepository extends CrudRepository<ResourceDAOImpl, Long>, Serializable {

    ResourceDAOImpl findById(Long primaryKey);

}
```

ResourcesEndpoint.java

```
@Controller
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping(value = "charts/resources", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class ResourcesEndpoint {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResourcesEndpoint.class);

    @Resource
    private ResourcesRepository resourcesRepository;

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    public ResponseEntity getAll() {
        log.info("GET-Request: '/'");
        try {
            return new ResponseEntity(this.mapper.writeValueAsString(this.resourcesRepository.findAll()), HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ResponseEntity(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    private ResponseEntity success(long counter) {
        if(this.resourcesRepository.count() < counter)
            return new ResponseEntity("alles ok", HttpStatus.OK);
        return new ResponseEntity("nix craft", HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT);
    }


}
```

Now I get the following errormessages:

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
>   refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'resourcesEndpoint': Injection of resource
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'resourcesRepository': Cannot create inner
>   bean '(inner bean)#51599d91' of type
>   [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting
>   bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#51599d91': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor
>   argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available

and

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> A component required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could
>   not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your
>   configuration.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I know my question is a little bit small and there is an answer for my question but I couldn't find it so far (I've been looking for this error for the past days).

Any hint will be appreciated, thanks!

Greetz

Comment: make sure your repository is scanned by  spring, provide base  package name in EnableJpaRepositories
```@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "your repositry package name" })```

Comment: adding `basePackages = {"com.domain.path.to.repo"}` doesn't work either :/

Comment: There are plenty of useless annotations in that sample: `EnableAutoConfiguration`, `ComponentScan` and `EntityScan` are all inferred by `SpringBootApplication` if it sits in `de.paddaels`. If it doesn't perhaps it should. I assume you have spring-boot-starter-data-jpa on the classpath? Try checking if a jar wasn’t corrupted in your local cache, mvn dependency:purge-local-repository

Comment: @StephaneNicoll If I don't use `ComponentScan` and `EntityScan` as I do, my application doesn't start.
`EnableAutoConfiguration` has been removed.
I solved my issue when I undid all changes (git ftw).

Comment: I wrote "if it sits in de.paddaels". If it doesn't, perhaps your application is at the wrong place? If you can move it, do so as it is better if Spring Boot can detect those things automatically.